# Поиск всех значений в TreeMap c "неполным" ключом

Tags: java, android

Доброго времени суток. Нужен совет, как найти все значения в `TreeMap` с "неполным" ключом. Допустим имеются какие то значения с ключами "Book","Boom","Trap"... При ключе "Boo" должен выводить значения у которых ключ начинается на этот кусок.

Пробовал использовать методы `ceilingKey(), floorKey(), higherKey(), lowerKey()`, но столкнулся с проблемой, выводит лишь одно значение. Попробовал удалять элементы после получения, тогда он выводит весь `TreeMap` пока не опустеет.

Может есть какой то более подходящий подход для этой задачи ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

На англоязычном SO есть [несколько таких](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13530999/fastest-way-to-get-all-values-from-a-map-where-the-key-starts-with-a-certan-expr) [вопросов с ответом](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10711494/get-values-in-treemap-whose-string-keys-start-with-a-pattern)

Идея такая: используем метод [subMap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/SortedMap.html#subMap(K,%20K)), первым параметром передаем наш префикс (или как вы говорите "неполный ключ"), вторым параметром передаем этот же неполный ключ, только с измененным последним символом, который на единицу больше предыдущего (либо можно просто в конец "неполного ключа" дописать `Character.MAX_VALUE`).

Answer (score 1):

Судя по [en-SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13531376/3212712) можно так:

```
public SortedMap<String, Object> getByPreffix(NavigableMap<String, Object> myMap, String preffix )
{
    return myMap.subMap( preffix, preffix + Character.MAX_VALUE );
}
```